# reading one line at a time from a file in R

Tags: r

I have 6.6 million lines in a file.  Each line is different length.  I want to read, using R, one line at a time and based on whether a certain string is in that line or not, I want to write it in a file or reject it.

Comment: Do you really *have to* use R for this task? It doesn’t seem to be the best choice...

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
f1 = open('fileYouWantToWriteTo.txt','w')
with open('fileToBeRead.txt') as f:
    list(map(f1.write,filter(lambda x:'stringYouAreSearchingFor' in x, f)))
f1.close()
```